# How do I fix my mesh for a low poly paper model?

Tags: mesh, uv

I've been exploring Blender for the past month for a school project and my goal is to create a mesh for a low poly human head which I can transform to paper model in the end. I have been able to create the low poly version of the 3D human head model, but am currently having difficulties because when I convert the file to paper model, **the numbers and shapes on the mesh keeps on overlapping each other** (as shown in the image attached), so it's very hard to comprehend the file.

**Does anyone happen to know how I can manipulate the mesh? I tried using the UV editing option and unwrapping the model but I don't know why it's unwrapped to a single triangle (photo also attached).**

If any of you know the answer to this problem, please let me know. Thank you! Your help will be very much appreciated!

[image: mesh shapes and numbers overlapping each other]

[image: unwrapping results in a single triangle]

Comment: Hello and welcome :). I believe UV unwrapping is the best option here. I'd reccomend [this classic video from BlenderGuru](https://youtu.be/scPSP_U858k?t=11), to learn more about manual unwrapping. If you get stuck, we're here to help.

Comment: The resulting UV map can then be simply exported in a vector format - which could be useful, if you intend to print it.